# display inline-block doesn't work with width 100%

Tags: html, css

I want to have a checkbox and text input, both of them will be in one line, the text input is responsive. I tried display inline-block, it worked but I can't make the text input to fill rest of the screen with width 100%, it will go down, why?

https://jsfiddle.net/shk4v0ep/

```
<div>
  <div class="left-wrap">
    <input type="checkbox" value="others" />
    <label>Others</label>
  </div>
  <input type="text" value="" />
</div>

.left-wrap {
  display: inline-block;
}

input[type="text"] {
  display: inline-block;
  //width:100%; how to make the input to fill till the rest of the screen
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Flexbox for that. Simply add a class to your container, and use `display: flex`. Then, add `flex: 1` to your input:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.left-wrap,
input[type="text"] {
  display: inline-block;
}

input[type="text"] {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left-wrap">
    <input type="checkbox" value="others" />
    <label>Others</label>
  </div>
  <input type="text" value="" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
input[type="text"] {
  //display: inline-block;
  width: 98%; //how to make the input to fill till the rest of the screen
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td width="5%"><input type="checkbox" value="others" /></td>
      <td width="5%"><label>Others</label> </td>
      <td><input type="text" value="" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Another approach to code. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

`width: 100%` means it's 100% to the container (which is the parent div).

**Approach 1**: You can do it with a table, like this:

```
<table style="width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" value="others" />
            <label>Others</label>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 100%;">
            <input type="text" value="" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Approach 2**: Set width to the `.left-wrap`, and keep changing the widths as you like:

```
.left-wrap {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25%; /* change this as you like */
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type="text"] {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 75%; /* change this as you like */
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

But make sure the sum of both widths don't exceed 100%.

And of course, there are other approaches, like using `flex` or `float`.